# Смешанное выравнивание блоков с помощью Bootstrap 4

Tags: flexbox, bootstrap4, разметка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью Bootstrap 4 выполнить вот такую разметку:

[image: Пример разметки]

1. Первый случай - ширины гораздо больше, чем нужно для помещения элементов в одну строку. Блоки 1,2,3 прижимаются влево, а блок 4 - вправо;
2. Второй случай - ширины впритык. По-сути выравнивания блоков аналогичны предыдущему случаю, но визуально блоки просто соприкасаются;
3. Третий случай - ширины для размещения всех четырех блоков в одну строку недостаточно. Блоки должны разместиться в две линии. При этом блоки 1,3 должны быть прижаты влево, а блоки 2,4 - вправо.

**Важно!**

Желательно использовать flex-элементы bootstrap 4 и, по возможности, не использовать дополнительные стили через CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, оказалось все просто:

```html
<section class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap flex-grow-1 justify-content-between">
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```